# Code for inverse sin, cos and tan

Tags: java, geometry

I'm writing a program which calculates the length of sides, angle measures at each vertex (in degrees) and the area of the triangle. The triangle is defined by the x and y-coordinates of its three vertices which are the user input.

I already finished methods calculating the length of sides and currently I'm trying to use law of cosines to find one of the angles. I need help in this area:

**Does anyone know code calculating inverse sin, cos and tan with the answer in degrees?**

This is more mathematical question but if somebody could help I would appreciate it. I also don't know **how to find the height of the triangle knowing its length of sides**. It would be needed to find the area in the next method I will be writing.

test:

```
public double getAngleA() {
    double angleA = Math.acos((side2 * side2 + side3 * side3 - side1 * side1)/(2.0 * side2 * side3));
    double angleA = Math.toDegrees(angleA);  
    return angleA;
}
```

Object Class:

```
public class Triangle
{
 private double x1;
 private double y1;
 private double x2;
 private double y2;
 private double x3;
 private double y3;
 private double sideA;
 private double sideB;
 private double sideC;
 private double angleA;
 private double angleB;
 private double angleC;



  public Triangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
  {
 this.x1 = x1;
 this.y1 = y1;
 this.x2 = x2;
 this.y2 = y2;
 this.x3 = x3;
 this.y1 = y3;
  }
   public double getSideC()
  {
  sideC = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
  return sideC;
   }
  public double getSideA()
  {
  sideA = Math.sqrt((x2-x3)*(x2-x3) + (y2-y3)*(y2-y3));
    return sideA; 
  }
   public double getSideB()
  {
  sideB = Math.sqrt((x1-x3)*(x1-x3) + (y1-y3)*(y1-y3));
  return sideB ;
  }
  public double getAngleA() {

  double angleA = Math.acos((sideB * sideB + sideC * sideC - sideA * sideA)/(2.0 * sideB * sideC));
  angleA = Math.toDegrees(angleA);  
  return angleA;
   }
    public double getAngleB() {

  double angleB = Math.asin((Math.sin(angleA) * sideB)/sideA); 
  return angleB;
   }
     public double getAngleC() {

  double angleC = 180 - (angleA+angleB);
  return angleC;
   }


}
```

Tester:

```
public class TriangleTester {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Triangle t = new Triangle (1, 2, 9, 7, 7, 10);
    System.out.println(t.getSideC());
  }


}
```

Expected Output: about 9.43398
Actual Output: 8.54400374531753

How do I fix it?

Comment: You can use `Math.sin()` `Math.cos()` & `Math.tan()`

Comment: @Shaggy: No, the question is about ***inverse*** functions, but these are also available in `Math`.

Comment: The question shows a lack of evidence of effort and initiative as all this information is easily findable, and the author shows none of the fruits of his own efforts. Hence my down-vote.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for needed criticism. Next time I will show my work.

Comment: There are formulas out there to calculate area of a triangle directly from either the coordinates of the corners or the lengths of the three sides. Use your favourite search engine.

Comment: Thank you. I better use the one with coordinates because my distance formula doesn't work well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [java.util.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) utility class has the arc sin method, `asin(...)`, that returns the radian result which can then be converted via Math's `toDegrees(...)` method to degrees.

Comment: @Life4Pancakes: you should include some text with that code. For example does the code answer your question? Does it not work? If so, what problems are you having with it? Also formatting counts -- note the change in formatting that I've given it.

Comment: I'll find out if it works when I finish this class and write main to it. It's going to take a while. Later I will paste my work and probably ask more questions...

Comment: I can't even check if my law of cosines if good because my distance formula doesn't work. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @Life4Pancakes: why or how is your distance formula failing you?

Comment: I edited the post (pasted my object and main class). As you can see at the end expected and actual outputs don't match. I don't know why.

Comment: @Life4Pancakes: the calculations are correct. Your code is broken though in that your methods all must be called in a certain order, else it fails. Better to either 1) do all calculations in the constructor and save the results, or 2) do all necessary calculations in each method, meaning you don't rely on any fields in methods other than the x and y fields.

Comment: It helped! Thank you